# SharePoint 2010: Solution for MS Office protocol URL scheme?

Tags: 2010, document-library, office-integration

I have a client still running a SharePoint Server 2010 on-prem, so opening documents from a library in MS Office applications only works with IE and the ActiveX controls which SP2010 incorporates.

Since SharePoint 2013 and above have a fallback mechanism for non-IE browsers to use MS Office URI schemes (ms-word:, ms-excel: etc.), I was wondering if there's any possibility (is there a SP solution around or the like?) to have this in SharePoint 2010 as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for Chrome this extension [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en) it will open tab as Internet Explorer so you can use here ActiveX controls.

It should help. We haven't installed SP2010 so I can not test it.

Comment: While I have found this as a workaround in quite a lot of answers, that's not exactly what I'm looking for since some of my users just "want it running" without having to install and configure a browser extension..

Comment: So there is no way how to achieve it, ActiveX controls are only in Internet Explorer and they are used for openning 'View in Explorer'.